# Keep the selected options after submitting the form

Tags: javascript, php

Good morning, I have a problem that is: I can not keep several options selected after submitting the form and I would like someone to help me.

```
<select name="utilizadores[]" id="utilizadores" multiple="multiple" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-actions-box="true" title="Utilizadores">
<?php  while ($reg_sql=mysqli_fetch_array($res_sql)){?>

<option value="<?php echo $reg_sql['ID_USER']; ?>"><?php echo $reg_sql['NOMEUSER']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>  
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('utilizadores').value = "<?php echo $_POST['utilizadores[]'];?>";
</script>
```

this is my code to have the various options in the select box

Comment: just add a "selected" attribute when your value matches with the POST data...

Comment: And how I do that ? Can you help me please ?

Comment: by writing some code which checks the value of the option being printed, and whether it matches the option selected in the POST. Just an if statement really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check if $_POST['utilizadores'] or $_GET['utilizadores'] it depends on your request type. I will use $_POST in  here for explain my answer.

your select is multiple, you can use in_array function for checking that if result from db record is in array of $_POST['utilizadores']

```
<select name="utilizadores[]" id="utilizadores" multiple="multiple" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-actions-box="true" title="Utilizadores">

     <?php  while ($reg_sql=mysqli_fetch_array($res_sql)){?>

     **<option value="<?php echo $reg_sql['ID_USER']; ?>"
        <?php 
            if(isset($_POST['utilizadores'])){
              if(in_array($reg_sql['ID_USER'], $_POST['utilizadores'])){
                 echo 'selected';
              }else{
                echo '';
              }
           }
         ?>
     >**<?php echo 
          $reg_sql['NOMEUSER']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>  
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks @AndréTavares

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do it more efficiently if your database result also contains which rows are selected, but when you loop through, just add the `selected="selected"` attribute to the `<option>` tag.

Assuming your `$_POST` array exists in this scope, you can use the `in_array` function in PHP to determine if the option has been selected ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)).

The ternary based operation is as follows:

`in_array($reg_sql['ID_USER'],$_POST['utilizadores']) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''`

Which says "if the ID_USER is in the post array, then print the selected attribute, otherwise, print a blank string"

Putting it all together:

```
<select name="utilizadores[]" id="utilizadores" multiple="multiple" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-actions-box="true" title="Utilizadores">
    <?php  while ($reg_sql=mysqli_fetch_array($res_sql)){?>
        <option value="<?php echo $reg_sql['ID_USER']; ?>" <?= in_array($reg_sql['ID_USER'],$_POST['utilizadores']) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' $?>>
            <?php echo $reg_sql['NOMEUSER']; ?>
        </option>
<?php } ?>  
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

An example of how you can do this. Either add the "selected" string if yes or leave blank if no. You can also write selected="selected". You can do the same thing to set disabled or readonly.

```
<select name="utilizadores[]" id="utilizadores" multiple="multiple" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-actions-box="true" title="Utilizadores">
<?php  while ($reg_sql=mysqli_fetch_array($res_sql)){?>
<?php $selected = isset($reg_sql["mi_variable"]) ? "selected" : ""; ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $reg_sql['ID_USER'];?>" <?php echo $selected; ?> >
        <?php echo $reg_sql['NOMEUSER']; ?>
    </option>
<?php } ?>  
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById('utilizadores').value = "<?php echo $_POST['utilizadores[]'];?>";
</script>
```